# How to convert Enumerable value to right format?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have the following code:

```
Client data = this.controllerPacients.getById(id).AsEnumerable()
                .Select(row => new Client
                           { 
                             taxcode = Convert.ToInt32(row.Field<int>("taxcode")).ToString()

                           })
               .Single();
```

So, in database field `taxcode` is integer. In model `Client` is string.

I get an error in this line, when try to convert types:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Attachment:

[image]

I tried this way also:

```
DataTable data =  db.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM table where id =4");

 var c = data.Rows[0].Field<int>("taxcode");
```

Comment: Are you want to use parentheses to execute integer conversion first: `taxcode = (Convert.ToInt32(row.Field<int>("taxcode"))).ToString()`?

Comment: I am not sure, because I dont understand meaning of error. But I assume that problem is in types.

Comment: Is that `taxcode` in `Client` class a string property? The conversion order determines the result type when assigning to that property, ensure `ToString` is the last to be processed.

Comment: Yes, string, I wrote this above.

Comment: Is there any reason why your model is of another type than the field in the database ? I mean, why would you store an int value into a string ?

Comment: The exception could be from anywhere - Please provide entire stacktrace.  Other than that, have you checked that the int column in the database isn't nullable?

Comment: I converted taxcode to int in model. The same error.

Comment: Is your `taxcode` in database a nullable column? It's better to use `int` property in `Client` class (matching data type in `DataTable`).

Comment: In database taxcode is not empty

Comment: Have you checked that the value is actually there in your datarow?  During debug runtime, check the value...  is THAT empty?

Comment: How to provide ` entire stacktrace`?

Comment: You should see the exception details somewhere in your IDE (visual studio?) when the error is thrown, and you can find the stack trace in the details of that exception object.

Comment: @user3573738: have you tried to use debugger? Look inside `row` object and check *actual* value type for "taxcode" field.

Comment: Wait please. In itemArray I can see object with taxcode value

Comment: Then if you have same type in model and in db, you don't have to cast anymore...

Comment: It is weird, but problem is exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:

```
Client data = this.controllerPacients.getById(id).AsEnumerable().Select(row => new Client {
   taxcode = Convert.ToInt32(row["taxcode"])
}).Single();
```

Where `Single();` extracts first row from result DataTable. The I get value by key of field:

```
Convert.ToInt32(row["taxcode"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to reply to this question with an inappropriate answer...  I'm going to break your question down and explain why it's a horrible question...

In your code:

```
Client data = this.controllerPacients.getById(id).AsEnumerable()
                .Select(row => new Client
                           { 
                             taxcode = Convert.ToInt32(row.Field<int>("taxcode")).ToString()

                           })
               .Single();
```

... you fail to explain ANY of it.  Here are some points:

a) `controllerPacients` which you've spelled incorrectly by the way, is a class-level property which could be hiding a cast within it, meaning we'd never be able to see the bug here on stack overflow.  You should provide the ENTIRE code, or fill in any gaps with an explanation.

b) `getById(id)` returns you some array-like type, but we can't see what it is.  Using `AnEnumerable` in a situation like this has some serious code-smell.  Isn't there a way you can `select` directly from the getById result, or access what appears to be the row collection via a property of the getById result?

c) 25 thousand casts...  If the field is an `int` and your class has a `string`, just use `.ToString()` you don't need all this conversion going on.

d) You should probably consider creating a method on the Client class which takes a Patient as a parameter and loads it's values from that, rather than loading from the original Patient's datasource.  For example `Client.LoadTaxCodeFromPatient(Patient)`

e) You're having to put a `Single()` call at the end of what shouldn't be a collection anyway, if `getById` returns anything other than a `Patient` class it's doing something wrong.

Sorry for beating your question up like that, but sometimes I just gotta :)

Comment: I can demonstrate result of  `this.controllerPacients.getById`

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Problem is that another line works: `datebirth = row.Field<String>("datebirth").ToString()`